# mongoose query is behaving in strange way

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB with mongoose as ORM library for my NodeJS project. Here I am putting two versions of same query, the problem is NoSqlBooster version is returning value correctly, where mongoose version is returning empty array, Please find the both versions of the query.

NoSQLBooster Version:

```
db.users.find({
  isDeleted: false,
  skills: { '$in': [ ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbcc'), ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbcd') ] },
  interests: { '$in': [ ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbce'), ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbcf') ] },
  university: { '$in': [ ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbd0'), ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbd1') ] },
  title: { '$in': [ ObjectId('613b785b7bacfe1336ab9dbf'), ObjectId('613b9951e42a5203c421cbd2') ] }
});
```

which is working perfectly, but when I am pushing the same query on mongoose find() its returning empty array. Please find the mongoose version below.

```
{
  isDeleted: false,
  skills: { '$in': [ '613b9951e42a5203c421cbcc', '613b9951e42a5203c421cbcd' ] },
  interest: { '$in': [ '613b9951e42a5203c421cbce', '613b9951e42a5203c421cbcf' ] },
  university: { '$in': [ '613b9951e42a5203c421cbd0', '613b9951e42a5203c421cbd1' ] },
  title: { '$in': [ '613b785b7bacfe1336ab9dbf', '613b9951e42a5203c421cbd2' ] }
}
```

Please note, above is the request I get from frontend itself, I am just pushing it to find.

Please find the schema structure for these specific fields,

```
{
  skills: [ 
    { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Skills" }
  ],
  interests: [
    { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Interests" }
  ],
    university: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "University" }],
    title: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Titles"}]
}
```

here is the find() function that I am using,

```
if (
        this.req.body &&
        this.req.body.filterParam &&
        !_.isEmpty(this.req.body.filterParam)
      ) {
        makeQuery = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.req.body.filterParam));
      } 

      if(_.isEmpty(this.req.body.searchText) && _.isEmpty(this.req.body.filterParam)) {
        makeQuery = { isDeleted: false };
      }
      console.log(makeQuery);
      let getListOfUsers = await Users.find(makeQuery)
        .sort(sort)
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(perPage)
        .populate("skills", { type: 1 }, { isDeleted: false })
        .populate("interests", { type: 1 }, { isDeleted: false })
        .populate("university", { type: 1 }, { isDeleted: false })
        .populate("business_tags", { type: 1 }, { isDeleted: false })
        .populate("title", { type: 1 }, { isDeleted: false })
        .populate("likesUserManagement", { likedFlag: 1 }, { isDeleted: false, likedFlag: true, createdBy: currentUser })
        .select({
          password: 0,
          status: 0,
          emailVerificationStatus: 0,
          isProfileCompleted: 0,
          isDeleted: 0,
          previouslyUsedPasswords: 0,
          ifForgetOtpVerified: 0,
          portfolio_name: 0,
          portfolio_s3_name: 0,
          image_name: 0,
          createdAt: 0,
          updatedAt: 0,
          __v: 0,
        });
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. I am stuck with this. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to make your IDs in arrays like the first one? I mean with ObjectId()

Comment: Yes, still no Luck.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful if you can share your mongoose schema file.

Comment: What do you mean by it's returning nothing? Is it an empty array or object or something? Please specify. Also, which of the mongoose function you are using? users.find()?

Comment: @ikoujar schema structure added

Comment: @Ammar, its an empty array, corrected the question. If you can figure out some error let me know pls.

Comment: I can't see isDeleted in your schema!, try to remove isDeleted from conditions and check the result.

Comment: That isDeleted is there in the schema, just didn't add it in the snapshot.

Comment: Ok maybe if you can share how you are calling the "find" function in mongoose will help.

Comment: I have shared the whole thing that I been doing, I still can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I had a spelling mistake, sorry guys I wasted your time.